# É possível configurar props default nos componentes vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Bem galera o que eu gostaria de saber é se há alguma maneira de configurar os valores default das props dos componentes vuetify? Para que eu não tenha que repetir as props todas as vezes que usar o componente no estilo que desejo.

Como no exemplo a seguir em que tenho que colocar 5 props para ter o estilo que desejo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
      <v-text-field
        placeholder="Nome"
        outlined
        flat
        dense
        solo
        required
      ></v-text-field>
  </v-app>
</div>
  
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente o que eu aconselho nesse caso é isolar o componente de vuetify com as `props` *default* em um outro componente em sua aplicação. Fiz um exemplo abaixo bem simples, porém na sua aplicação eu aconselho a usar um *single file component* ao invés de `Vue.component`.

```js
Vue.component('field', {
  props: ['value'],
  data: function () {
    return {
      valueData: 0
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.valueData = this.value  
  },
  watch: {
    valueData: function(newValue) {    
      this.$emit('input', newValue);
    }    
  },
  template: `<v-text-field
        placeholder="Nome"
        outlined
        flat
        dense
        solo
        v-model.sync="valueData"
        required
      ></v-text-field>`
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    valueExample: '5'
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
      <field v-model="valueExample"/>      
  </v-app>  
</div>
```

Desta forma fica mais simples, mas realmente eu não aconselho esta abordagem se não tiver pelo menos algumas `props` que você repasse para o componente do Vuetify, senão o custo de manutenção futura pode ser alto.
Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado mas tenho uma duvida: Porque é melhor usar single file component ao invés de Vue.component?

Comment: Eu não tenho muito conhecimento em Vue.component, mas não sei dizer se é possível fazer lazy load com Vue.component. Também acho que para ver o código em si e dar manutenção depois fica mais simples com SFC. Mas realmente, para este caso em específico que você passou, acho que não importa muito se é SFC ou Vue.component.